# Slang words for body parts

Tags: slang

We all know the various slang words for bottoms, boobs and genitalia. Those are well covered here already. This question relates to slang words for the other parts of the body.

What common slang words do we have for body parts (aside from the "good bits" mentioned above). For example: "noggin" for your head. Alternatively, "peepers" for your eyes (though urban dictionary says this can also mean breasts).

Comment: @Orbit: Thank you for the question but this is way too broad. Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve? Otherwise, all we have here is a list of terms for a category of words from a thesaurus or urban dictionary? That's not really the best way to get information from this type of Q&A. "How many words can you name for..." is not really what this site is about. If you have a *specific* problem you are trying to solve, please feel free to try again.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: I do believe we have other, similarly broad community wiki questions, like the one asking for words that are commonly mispronounced by educated speakers, and many others. The latter question got huge amounts of votes, as did its answers, and frankly I liked it too. I'm not so sure the current question is any different from the other community wiki lists we have.

Answer (score 5):

- *Hands* has: *paw, mitt, duke, hook, meathook*.
- *Feet*: *tootsies, dogs, boats, trotters*.
- *Head*: *nut, noodle, dome, noggin*
- *Brain*: *gray matter*, *smarts*
- For *eyes*, in addition to *peepers*, I'll go with *baby blues*
- *Belly*: *tummy, tum, breadbasket, gut, guts, insides, pot, potbelly, beer belly, spare tire*.
- *Bottom*: *cheeks, behind, butt, booty, fanny, keister, tush, tail, buns, caboose, duff, heinie, ass, fundament, posterior, sit-upon, stern, bum, arse*.
- *Teeth*: *choppers*.

Comment: Isn't your noodle your brain? And your tootsies your toes?

Comment: @MrHen: NOAD has “noodle: a person's head”

Comment: Odd. I feel safe in declaring that "noodle=brain" makes a lot more sense than "noodle=head".

Answer (score 1):

I found these entries:

- **Armor**: body;
- **Cum deflectors**: Eyeglasses (not really a body part but...);
- **Grill**: teeth/mouth/mouth jewelry;
- **Blower**: also mouth;
- **Afro**: any large hair style;
- **Dome**: head *and - be careful - this can also be* fellatio;
- **Clickers**: a full set of dentures;
- **Gam**: leg;
- **Cuts**: muscles;
- **Outie**: a navel that bugles outward, opposed to **innie**;
- **Banus**: perineum `[Etymology: this term is a contraction of "balls" (testicles) and "anus."]` - The Perineum is the zone between those two parts;
- **Dunlop**: a large stomach.

Comment: A dunlop? For some reason that one prompted me to respond. Never heard that one.

Comment: Perhaps "Dunlop" as in spare tire.

Comment: A contraction of "balls" and "anus" sounds particularly painful.

Comment: A Dunlop is a spare tire -- and it done lop over your belt.

Comment: The perineum is so commonly called the "taint" nowadays that the first word is almost lost.  Seriously, a friend of mine asked me if there was a non-slang word for taint. I couldn't help myself, I answered, "In the male, it's called the 'perineum'; in the female, of course, it's called the 'chin rest'."  True story.

Comment: @Malvolio: It has a different name for females? I didn't know that... Unless it's different in Italian. @Robusto: that upvote on your comment was mine. Every time I read it, it makes me wanna laugh LOL

Comment: @Alenanno -- The Italian word you should be considering at this moment is *barzelletta*.  Unless you don't know what a [chin rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chin_rest) really is.

Comment: @Malvolio: LOL uhm... I guess you got me there. But barzelletta is a different thing. It's a short story that makes you laugh, the typical "A horse goes to a bar, etc..." lol but maybe you meant a joke? In that case, _battuta_ sounds better. :D

Comment: @Alenanno -- *battuta* is an interesting word.  It seems cognate with "batter", "bat", and "baton".  I guess a *battuta* is a stroke of wit.  Perhaps my whole comment could be construed as a *barzelletta* about my making a *battuta*.

Comment: @Malvolio: _Battuta_ can be either when you use your bat in the Baseball game, or when you do a single joke, like a sentence or a word... A _barzelletta_ is a whole story, short, but still a story to make your audience laugh. :)